# vue router: go up one (variable) level

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

seems nobody had this question before...? (or i just don't know the right words for it :D )

i want to have a very basic heading on every page of my app, which allows the user to go "up". simple as that.

example: user is on `page.com/users/browse/`, clicks on the heading, gets navigated to `page.com/users/`, clicks again, gets navigated to `page.com`. nothing more. it just has to be variable, so i can put it in a component and have it just work everywhere

how can i do that? i tried vue.$route, but there is only a string of the complete url. is there any convenient way to do it? or do i HAVE to split the url by `/` and build the route myself?

thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using this: `this.$router.replace("./");`

I don't know how it is working though. The single dot(`./`) will go up one path and double dots(`../`) will go up 2 paths!

Answer (score 1):

This functionality has a name "Breadcrumbs".
Check this: [1](http://npmjs.com/package/vue-breadcrumbs), [2](http://npmjs.com/package/vue-2-crumbs), [3](http://npmjs.com/package/vue-crumbs)  or look for this in your framework.

Comment: but i'll still have to manage those manually, don't i? is there a way to use this to "go up, no matter where you are" (without having to specify where you actually are beforehand)?

Comment: You need one time set params of breadcrcumbs in routes array only. 
See more:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-breadcrumbs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-2-crumbs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-crumbs

Comment: i've read into it, but i don't have nested routes unfortunately :/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a method for going up one level by getting the route's path and then splitting it. Here's what worked for me:

```
upOneLevel(){
  var upperPath = this.$route.path.split("/")

  if(upperPath.length > 0) {
    upperPath.splice(upperPath.length-1)
    this.$router.push(upperPath.join("/"))
  }
}
```

Then you can add a button that calls this method to go up by one level but no further than the root. This method will work regardless of whether or not your routes were nested properly.

Answer (score 1):

`this.$router.replace("./")` will help if the user clicks on the heading only once, if he try to clicks again nothing is happen because [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) [avoid redundant navigation to the same location.](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort)
You can catch this error then navigate to the root, (or to a [named route](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html)) if you have only two levels in your routes.

> ###### NOTE :
>
> This function works only for two levels (see the example of this Question)

```
goUp() {
            this.$router.replace("./").then(err =>{
                if(err) 
                    this.$router.replace("/"); 
                    // or : this.$router.replace({name:"home"}); for named routes
          })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current path using `this.$route.path` and than remove the last party by splitting/splicing it:

```
goUp(){
    var upperPath = this.$route.path.split("/")
    if (upperPath.length > 2) {
        upperPath.splice(upperPath.length - 1)
        this.$router.push(upperPath.join("/"))
    } else {
        this.$router.push('/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The already mentioned `this.$router.replace("./");` will add a trailing slash.

If this is not your intention, use `this.$router.replace(".");`

Moreover, if you want to make a [new history event](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#replace-current-location), use `this.$router.push(".");`